# Deleting an element from dictionary array in javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, dictionary

$scope.couponMatches = {};

I have a function which adds elements to a dictionary:
$scope.couponMatches[$scope.currentMatch] = { firstElemet: "a", secondElement: "b" };

Every time I call this function it adds an elemet to my dictionary

EX:
-MND3sdaDFFls2s : { firstElemet: "a", secondElement: "b" }
-MGHuwenSN3mndb : { firstElemet: "a", secondElement: "b" }

In firebase I save it .

I need to delete one element with an index before save it to firebase.

Answer (score 0):

You have a reserved word `delete` specially for this case.

Lets say you want to delete property `a` from object `obj`, use:

```
delete obj.a
```